# How to RESET running code on Intel Galileo

Tags: linux, arduino, intel-galileo

I am working on Intel Galileo board(Linux running on board) and using arduino as development environment.

Now on getting a particular gpio pin(say digital pin 6) logic 1, I want to reset my code automatically. 
I want reset done by running sketch on its own(i.e. I don't have press RESET button).

I am not using SD card Image.

I am unable to interpret how it should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following line to reset the sketch, without the inconvenience of a board reboot:

```
system("./opt/cln/galileo/galileo_sketch_reset_script.sh");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll be able to reboot your board by calling in your sketch the system command:

```
system("reboot");
```

But there might be a better solution for your main goal. Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to accomplish doing this?

Comment: As I am not using not using SD card image, so when I reboot the sketch is erased from board

Comment: Why do you need to reset your sketch by code? To keep it persistent you'll also need to use an SD card

Comment: I am working on an application in which user controlling some motors through relays, So I have a demand from user to have  reset option also.

Comment: I have posted an answer that worked for me, I got it from intel forum